# Javascript if statement doesnt work boolean

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

[image]

Hello
, I am making a rock paper scissors game to exercise with javascript. But i don't get why this code doesn't work. if I activate function start then var begin is supposed to be true but when I, for example, activate function rock then it doesn't say rock in the console.
Can someone help me?

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question.

Comment: You are a victim of hoisting

Comment: Please include your code in your question (as a working snippet if possible) rather than an image of your code.

Comment: Remove the `var` keyword from `var begin = true;`

Comment: thanks!!!! i feel dumb xd

Comment: Glad you see the problem (the extraneous "var begin") :)  In the future, please copy/paste your text (instead of a screen shot).  Even better, consider using "code snippets".  Please also read about Javascript [hoisting](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) and the ES6 keyword [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 1):

By adding **var** in start function you're declaring another local variable **start**.

Replace start function with

```
function start(){
    begin = true;
    console.log("start");
    document.getElementById("player").id = "current";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `var begin` inside of the `start()` function you declare a new local variable. If you set that to `true` the outer variable with the same name won't be affected. To set the outer one instead, don't declare the variable but just set it:

```
 begin = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only set begin to true within the scope of the start function. If you change the start code to `begin = true` it should work.

When you declared `var begin` inside your start function that variable was scoped to the function. And when you accessed begin in the other functions you were accessing the global begin which had never been changed from false